# How to find the zeroes of a BCH code and how do they define the dimensions of a parity check matrix?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm looking through the lecture notes by Alexandar Barg ENEE626:Error-Correcting Codes Lecture 13.

We are given an example which says:

"Consider the Hamming Code $H_{4}[15,11,3]$.

Let $\alpha$ be a primitive $14^{th}$ root of unity. We can construct a BCH code $C$ with zeroes $\alpha$ and $\alpha_{3}$. The parity check matrix is:

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} & \alpha^{3} & \alpha^{4} & \dots & \alpha^{14} \\
1 & \alpha^{3} & \alpha^{6} & \alpha^{9} & \alpha^{12} & \dots & \alpha^{12}
\end{bmatrix} $$

This is a $8$ by $15$ parity check matrix with all eight rows linearly independent. So, we have to a $[15,7]$ code. Note that the dimension is $n-2m$, which will be true for any BCH code. It remains to prove that $d=5$."

My question is, how do we know that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{3}$ are the zeroes? And how is the above parity check matrix an $8$ by $15$ matrix? It looks like a $2$ by $15$ matrix?

Comment: A few things caught my eye in your quote. Surely $\alpha$ needs to be a $15^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity. Also, the dimension of a BCH code is not always $n-2m$. It can be higher, if $\alpha^{2i+1}$ belongs to a proper subfield for some $i<m$, or (for relatively large values of $m$), several such powers are each others conjugates.

Comment: To answer your question I need to know a bit more about your background (as well as other pieces described [in our abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619)). Are you familiar with the check matrix of the Hamming code? It is, after all, the "same" code as the single-error-correcting BCH-code. Defined by the top row of the given check matrix $H$. The same process turns a single check equation with coefficients in an extension field into $m$ binary check equations. The latter are what you need  when calculating the dimension.

Comment: There is something wrong with the statement in the Lecture Notes. The $[15.11,3]$ Hamming code is a _single_ error correcting code and its parity check matrix has only one row (the first shown and not then two that are shown), and its parity check matrix is a $4\times 15$ _binary_ matrix obtained by expressing the the $\alpha^I$'s as column vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had asked because there seemed to be a few contradicting statements in the lecture notes, so I assumed I had missed something, but it seems that there are inaccuracies in the lecture notes.
I agree @JyrkiLahtonen that it should be $\alpha$ is a $15^{th}$ root of unity.  
Yes, I am familiar with the check matrix of the Hamming code, but probably don't have an in-depth enough understanding as I am not understanding how the parity check matrix above in question is a $8 \times 15$ matrix, when it appears to be a $2 \times 15$ matrix

Comment: Apologies, actually I think I totally misinterpreted what was happening. The $\alpha^{i}$'s are the primitive elements of $F_{15}$ and as such, their expression in binary are the columns of the matrix, hence why it is a $4 \times 15$ matrix. 
And hence why, in the question, it says it is an $8 \times 15$ matrix, because it assumed that it was double-error correcting code (which appears to be incorrect)

Comment: So how about writing up and posting an answer to your question, pointing out the mis-statements in the Lecture Notes so that this question does not appear repeatedly in the list of Unanswered Questions. This action is perfectly acceptable on math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

**"Let $\alpha$ be a $14^{th}$ root of unity"**

This statement is **false**, as the *$n^{th}$ roots of unity* are the roots of the polynomial $x^{n}-1$. As we are working over $\mathbb{F}_{15}$, $n=15$ and as such $\alpha$ must be a $15^{th}$ root of unity.

**"This is a $8$ by $15$ parity check matrix with all eight rows linearly independent. So, we have a [$15,7$] code. "**

The parity check matrix shown is incorrect. $H$ should only have one row of $\alpha$, as the {$15, 11, 3$] Hamming code is a SINGLE error correcting code. If it were a DOUBLE error-correcting code, then we would have two rows of $\alpha$ and $\alpha_{3}$ respectively.
Recall, the $\alpha_{i}$'s are the primitive elements of $\mathbb{F}_{15}$ and as the length of each of the primitive elements is $4$, then each of the elements of $\alpha$ consists of column vectors of length $4$ (the binary expression of the primitive elements).
As such, the parity check matrix is a $4 \times 15$ matrix rather than an $8 \times 15$ matrix as the lecture notes had suggested.